# convert local video file into media stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I want to experiment file streaming using webRTC. It works perfectly with the camera/micro live (getUserMedia) but when I try to give it a pre-recorderd video file, I got this answer :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addStream' on 'RTCPeerConnection': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStream'.
```

Is there a simple way to use RTCPeerConnection with selected files like with .getUserMedia() ?

**Edit:**

Here is how I get the file but when I try to add the 'localStream' with the addStream method of RTCPeerConnection, it fail...

```
var localVideo = document.createElement("video");
var remoteVideo = document.createElement("video");

function onchange( event ){

    var file = this.files[0];
    var type = file.type;

    if( localVideo.canPlayType(type) ){

        var localStream = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

        localVideo.src = localStream;

        ...

        peer.addStream(localStream); // fail here

    };

};
```

Comment: How are you trying to use the local video file? Could you post that code? FireFox has a built in object for this but Chrome does not.

Comment: Did you find a way? I need exactly this functionality.

Comment: related: [html - How to get media stream object form HTML5 video element in javascript - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458191/how-to-get-media-stream-object-form-html5-video-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

a) createObjectURL is evil.  You can never know when the application is done with the resource until the navigate away. (and other issues)  Use video.srcObject (video.mozSrcObject currently)

b) just because a video element can use a src URL for a streaming media file doesn't mean anything else can. AddStream takes MediaStreams, not URLs.

The Working Group is planning to add stream = video.captureStream(), but it isn't even speced yet

Update: the spec is here: [Media Capture from DOM Elements](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/)
It's implemented in Firefox, and Chrome 53 and above (see [Sam Dutton's article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/capture-stream))

Comment: Updated answer with links to spec and examples

Answer (score 1):

Create a `video` element with the video that you need:

```
<video controls src="http://example.com/example.webm">
```

When this video plays, you can retrieve the `MediaStream` object that you can reuse presumably for `RTCPeerConnection`:

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');
video.onplay = function() {
  const stream = video.captureStream();
  peer.addStream(stream);
};
```

This works in the same way for an `audio` element.